# Psycopg2 "copy_from" command, possible to ignore delimiter in quote (getting error)?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to load rows of data into postgres in a csv-like structure using the copy_from command (function to utilize copy command in postgres). My data is delimited with commas(and unfortunately since I am not the data owner I cannot just change the delimiter). I run into a problem when I try to load a row that has a value in quotes containing a comma (ie. that comma should not be treated as a delimiter).

For example this row of data is fine:

```
",Madrid,SN,,SEN,,,SN,173,157"
```

This row of data is not fine:

```
","Dominican, Republic of",MC,,YUO,,,MC,65,162",
```

Some code:

```
    conn = get_psycopg_conn()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    _io_buffer.seek(0) #This buffer is holding the csv-like data
    cur.copy_from(_io_buffer, str(table_name), sep=',', null='', columns=column_names)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: What does the copy_from function look like?

Comment: @hdr http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[It looks like `copy_from` doesn't expose the `csv` mode or `quote` options](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from), which [are available form the underlying PostgreSQL `COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). So you'll need to either patch psycopg2 to add them, or [use `copy_expert`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert).

I haven't tried it, but something like

```
curs.copy_expert("""COPY mytable FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)""", _io_buffer)
```

might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Craig this answered my question. Unfortunately the data is being thrown out of order somewhere along the way, so unless I fix that issue will not get the chance to implement this. One step further though!

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks. Sad that Psycopg2 doesn't have these options built in.

Comment: @sudo Well, it's only sad until someone writes a patch to implement it. It's not overly hard to modify psycopg2.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and was able to get close to a fix based on the single line of code listed by [craig-ringer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer).  The other item I needed was to include quotes for the initial object by using `df.to_csv(index=False,header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,sep=',')` and specifically `, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`.

The full example of pulling one data source from MySQL and storing it in Postgres is below:

```
#run in python 3.6
import MySQLdb
import psycopg2
import os
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import csv

mysql_db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host_address",# your host, usually localhost
                     user="user_name",         # your username
                     passwd="source_pw",  # your password
                     db="source_db")       # name of the data base

postgres_db = psycopg2.connect("host=dest_address dbname=dest_db_name user=dest_user password=dest_pw")

my_list = ['1','2','3','4']

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let you execute all the queries you need
mysql_cur = mysql_db.cursor()
postgres_cur = postgres_db.cursor()

for item in my_list:
  # Pull cbi data for each state and write it to postgres
  print(item)
  mysql_sql = 'select * from my_table t \
       where t.important_feature = \'' + item + '\';'

  # Do something to create your dataframe here...
  df = pd.read_sql_query(mysql_sql, mysql_db)

  # Initialize a string buffer
  sio = StringIO()
  sio.write(df.to_csv(index=False,header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,sep=','))  # Write the Pandas DataFrame as a csv to the buffer
  sio.seek(0)  # Be sure to reset the position to the start of the stream

  # Copy the string buffer to the database, as if it were an actual file
  with postgres_db.cursor() as c:
      print(c)
      c.copy_expert("""COPY schema:new_table FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)""", sio)
      postgres_db.commit()

mysql_db.close()
postgres_db.close()
```