# Psycopg2 not auto generating id when using copy_from a csv file to Postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, copy, psycopg2

I have a csv file that has several columns:

`upc    date    quantity   customer`

In my `physical` table, I have an auto generating `id` column for each row:

`id    upc    date    quantity    customer`

It seems as though the db is interpreting the `upc` as the actual id when I run my python script to copy into the db. I'm getting this error message:

```
Error: value "1111111" is out of range for type integer
CONTEXT:  COPY physical, line 1, column id: "1111111"
```

I've never attempted this before, but I believe this is correct:

```
def insert_csv(f, table):
    connection = get_postgres_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(f, table, sep=',')
        connection.commit()
        return True
    except (psycopg2.Error) as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or do I have to create another script to get the last id from the table?

**Updated working code:**

```
def insert_csv(f, table, columns):
    connection = get_postgres_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        column_names = ','.join(columns)
        query = f'''
            COPY {table}({column_names})
            FROM STDOUT (FORMAT CSV)
        '''
        cursor.copy_expert(query, f)
        connection.commit()
        return True
    except (psycopg2.Error) as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

```
columns = (
        "upc",
        "date_thru",
        "transaction_type",
        "transaction_type_subtype",
        "country_code",
        "customer",
        "quantity",
        "income_gross",
        "fm_serial",
        "date_usage"
    )
```

```
with open(dump_file, 'r', newline='', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
        inserted = insert_csv(f, 'physical', columns)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify columns to import. From [the documentation:](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from)

> **columns** – iterable with name of the columns to import. The length and types should match the content of the file to read. If not specified, it is assumed that the entire table matches the file structure.

Your code may look like this:

```py
def insert_csv(f, table, columns):
    connection = connect()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(f, table, sep=',', columns=columns)
        connection.commit()
        return True
    except (psycopg2.Error) as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        
with open("path_to_my_csv") as file:
    insert_csv(file, "my_table", ("upc", "date", "quantity", "customer"))
```

If you have to use `copy_expert()` modify your function in the way as follow:

```py
def insert_csv(f, table, columns):
    connection = connect()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        column_names = ','.join(columns)
        copy_cmd = f"copy {table}({column_names}) from stdout (format csv)"
        cursor.copy_expert(copy_cmd, f)
        connection.commit()
        return True
    except (psycopg2.Error) as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Comment: Only problem now is that it's interpreting commas in strings as a separator (i.e. some customers have "Name, The").

Comment: Use [`copy_expert()`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) instead. Read also [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27055634/1995738)

Comment: I noticed that issue. However, when I try using that method it throws the same `id` error:
`value "1111111" is out of range for type integer`

Comment: You have not shown how you are using `copy_expert`, but I'm going to guess you are not supplying the column list to the `COPY` command per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): `COPY table_name [ column_name [, ...] ) ] FROM { 'filename' ...`. It is pretty basic the columns in the CSV file need to match those in the table, with any left of columns in the table being filled with their `DEFAULT` value. In the case of the `id` column that would be the `nextval` for the sequence.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

From here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html):

> If a column list is specified, COPY TO copies only the data in the specified columns to the file. For COPY FROM, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column. Table columns not specified in the COPY FROM column list will receive their default values.

So the values in the CSV file will be assigned left to right and the fields at the end of the table will get their `DEFAULT` values. If you don't want that to happen then from here [copy_from](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from):

> columns – iterable with name of the columns to import. The length and types should match the content of the file to read. If not specified, it is assumed that the entire table matches the file structure.

Create a list of columns that match the file structure, leaving out the `id` column which will be filled with the `sequence` values.