# Psycopg2 copy_from csv ignore commas in row

Tags: python, postgresql, copy, psycopg2

I am trying to copy a csv file into a postgres table (`phsyical`) using the psycopg2's `copy_from` method.

```
columns = (
    'upc',
    'date',
    'type',
    'country_code',
    'customer'
    )

def insert_csv(f, columns):
    connection = get_postgres_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.copy_from(f, 'physical', sep=',', columns=columns)
    connection.commmit()
```

I have an auto generated id for each row that I'm not including in the `columns`.

However, some of the rows have commas within the cells. When troubleshooting I can see the rows that have errors:

```
1111111,2021-02-28 00:00:00,,US,"Name, The"
```

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055634/psycopg2-copy-from-command-possible-to-ignore-delimiter-in-quote-getting-err) and tried:

```
cursor.copy_expert("COPY physical FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)", f)
```

But this causes an error I was running into earlier when not specifying the columns I wanted.

```
value "1111111" is out of range for type integer
CONTEXT:  COPY physical, line 1, column id: "1111111"
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

**Updated working code:**

```
def insert_csv(f, table, columns):
    connection = get_postgres_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        column_names = ','.join(columns)
        query = f'''
            COPY {table}({column_names})
            FROM STDOUT (FORMAT CSV)
        '''
        cursor.copy_expert(query, f)
        connection.commit()
        return True
    except (psycopg2.Error) as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

```
columns = (
        "upc",
        "date_thru",
        "transaction_type",
        "transaction_type_subtype",
        "country_code",
        "customer",
        "quantity",
        "income_gross",
        "fm_serial",
        "date_usage"
    )
```

```
with open(dump_file, 'r', newline='', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
        inserted = insert_csv(f, 'physical', columns)
```

Comment: This was already explained in your earlier question [psycopg2 copy_from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187284/psycopg2-not-auto-generating-id-when-using-copy-from-a-csv-file-to-postgres-db/70188401#comment124075639_70188401).

Comment: I just didn't know how to include the columns

Comment: I pointed you at the docs that showed how and @klin provided an updated example, so not sure how much more information could have been provided. Especially as the answer below is just a repeat of the update in the previous answer.

Comment: The suggestion you left on the other question I had "`COPY table_name [ column_name [, ...] ) ] FROM { 'filename' ...`" from the documentation is syntactically incorrect, and I apologize that I'm fairly new to this industry, but the docs themselves aren't very clear as to how the syntax should be structured `COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]...`. Luckily @klin was helpful enough to provide a solid example. Thanks to his assistance, I can now interpret that `[ ]` means "optional" within some (not all) documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the columns names in the copy command, e.g:

```py
column_names = ','.join(columns)
copy_cmd = f"copy physical({column_names}) from stdout (format csv)"
cursor.copy_expert(copy_cmd, f)
```

Comment: You're a wizard, thank you !